# How to integrate particles.js into bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to integrate particles.js (https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) into a bootstrap template I got and would like it to only appear in the little banner/container. I was able to successfully add all the scripts in my html document as well as link the css files, however I cannot edit the html such that the div id="particles-js" fits well in the container its either too wide, too small, or the particles are separate from the text. Any clues on how to properly integrate this? Here is a snippet of what I have. Currently I Have some_image.jpg as the background image for my banner and would like to replace it with particles-js

```
    <div class="bg-dark-black padding-100px-top bg-img cover-background " data-overlay-dark="0" data-background="img/some_image.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 order-2 order-md-1 padding-50px-tb sm-padding-30px-top sm-padding-70px-bottom">

                    <!-- Start banner Content -->
                    <div class="padding-thirty-tb sm-padding-fifteen-top xs-no-padding">
                        <h5 class="no-margin font-size18 xs-font-size16 text-medium-gray text-white">Hello, I'm</h5> ...
```

Comment: You will need to provide the whole page context or reproduce it in somewhere like JSFiddle for others to review and help you.

Comment: I did not include css and js for bootstrap. I just have my html and the css + js for particles-js on here https://jsfiddle.net/4u7mczaj/2/